# 'the limit must be specified as a number' error when using req.query.property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm doing a Mongoose/MongoDB `.aggregate` query with `$limit` in the pipeline. When I use a number, like `2`, it works fine. If I set a variable like `testNum = 2`, and then do `{$limit: varNum}`, it works fine. But if I send a REST query and try do `$limit: req.body.show`, it says the value is not a number.

I can see the value is a number through `console.log`. The other queries in the pipeline don't complain that they're not given numbers. Here is the code:

```
var show = req.query.show,  // the number of items to show per page
    page = req.query.page,  // the current page being asked for
    stream = req.params.stream, // the type of content to get
    skip = ( page > 0 ? (( page - 1 ) * show ) : 0 ), // amount to skip
    testNum = 3

console.log( show + " " + skip + " " + page )

Content.aggregate( [
    { $unwind: '$users' },
    { $group: { 
        _id: '$_id',
        title: { $first: '$title' },
        description: { $first: '$description' },
        images: { $first: '$images' },
        url: { $first: '$url' },
        saveCount: { $sum: 1 } } 
    },
    { $sort: { saveCount: -1 } },
    { $skip: skip },
    { $limit: show }
] )
.exec()
```

The query here is `?show=2&page=1`. The console output is `2 0 1`. That is working right.

The full error is here:

```
{ [MongoError: exception: the limit must be specified as a number]
name: 'MongoError',
errmsg: 'exception: the limit must be specified as a number',
code: 15957,
ok: 0 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason `show` is being treated like a string in the case of `$limit`, but nothing else seems to mind. I did this to fix it, but I think this might be a bug with Express or Mongoose/MongoDB. If anyone knows where to bring this up, let me know.

The fix is to use `parseInt` like this:

```
var show = parseInt( req.query.show ),  // the number of items to show per page
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the unary + operator too. `+req.query.show`